# Strange AV while loading an icon from the resource stream

Tags: delphi, resources, icons, delphi-xe2

I'm adding icons to my project via **Resources and Images** dialog, and decided to walk away from `TIcon.LoadFromResourceName` because it does not perform any error checking. I wrote seemingly equivalent code but does not work as expected.

Here is a testcase which fails for me:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
const
  ResName = 'Icon_1';
var
  Stream: TResourceStream;
begin
  OutputDebugString(PChar(Format('RTLVersion = %f', [RTLVersion])));
  Assert(Assigned(Image1), 'Image1 comes from the designer, should be instantiated already');

  Stream := TResourceStream.Create(HInstance, ResName, RT_GROUP_ICON);
  try
    Image1.Picture.Icon.LoadFromStream(Stream); // AV here
  finally
    Stream.Free;
  end;
end;
```

A/V occurs deeply inside library at **write of address 0x00000008**, which suggest some uninitialized object instance.

I'm doing anything wrong or it is a library bug? Library version is 23.0, Delphi XE2

Comment: Turn on debug DCUs and dig deeper to see what is being written to. You have a null pointer somewhere, which suggests you've neglected to create something by the time you run that code.

Comment: @Rob Kennedy, did you mean you cannot reproduce? I run this code in `OnCreate` event of isolated form of isolated "VCL Form Application" project. Image1 comes from the designer. Should I post the whole project?

Comment: Have you tried using `RT_ICON` instead of `RT_GROUP_ICON`?

Comment: @Remy Lebeau, yes, I did, got an expected failure from `TResourceStream.Create`. Also, confirmed a presence of resource and its type in the binary image with XN Resource Editor.

Comment: RT_GROUP_ICON deliveres access to a ICONDIRENTRY structure http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms997538.aspx  any of this icons contained have to be load by ID of this structure. A complete unit can be found here: http://www.delphipraxis.net/170682-laden-und-speichern-von-icons-icon-parser-fuer-icon-dateien-oder-resourcen.html

Comment: @bummi, are you sure about ICONDIRENTRY? I believe what it should be ICONDIR followed by actual N directory entries (same as standalone icon file) Thanks for the link, I'll take a look.

Comment: you are right, I missed one step, sorry ...

Comment: @bummi, could you please convert that comment to the answer? It is really valuable one.

Comment: I'm running out of time at the moment, feel free to answer your own question. As ist stands, it's just a comment, some extra work will have to be done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was confusing `RT_GROUP_ICON` and `RT_ICON`. `RT_GROUP_ICON` contains only icon header and directory ([`GRPICONDIR`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms997538#code-snippet-5) and [`GRPICONDIRENTRY`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms997538#code-snippet-6) respectively), but actual images and masks are stored separately as `RT_ICON` resources. Additionally, icon file headers and icon group headers have exactly same layout and magic values, making detection of invalid data stream impossible. Therefore, it is absolutely not possible to use `TIcon.LoadFromStream` with `RT_GROUP_ICON` resource, this method has been designed for disk files only.

Thanks to [**bummi**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1699210/bummi) for shedding a light onto this nuance.

Additional reading: [`LookupIconIdFromDirectoryEx` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/ms648074) reference and the corresponding [example code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/ms648051#_win32_Sharing_Icon_Resources).

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if you can load an `RT_GROUP_ICON` resource into a `TIcon` using `LoadFromStream()`, but there are alternate solutions:

```
Image1.Picture.Icon.Handle := LoadIcon(HInstance, ResName);
```

Or:

```
Image1.Picture.Icon.Handle := LoadImage(HInstance, ResName, IMAGE_ICON, 0, 0, LR_DEFAULTSIZE);
```

Or:

```
Image1.Picture.Icon.Handle := CreateIconFromResourceEx(PByte(Stream.Memory), Stream.Size, TRUE, $00030000, 0, 0, LR_DEFAULTSIZE);
```

Comment: Yes, I tried to walk away from `LoadIcon` based `TIcon.LoadFromResourceName`. Could you please confirm reproduction of described error?

Comment: I cannot test your code until tomorrow. Why do you think `TIcon.LoadFromResourceName()` does not do any error handling? It uses `TResourceStream` and `LoadFromStream()` internally, just like you do.

Comment: In my version of library (23.0) it merely does `SetHandle(LoadIcon(Instance, PChar(ResName)));`